# Ajax / How to make appended list item "selected"?

Tags: ajax

I am cycling through all values of items array and appending them to #selectbox like this:

```
    $("#Selectbox").append(
        $("<option></option>").attr(
            "value", items[i][0]).text(items[i][1])
    );
```

How within the same loop cycle I could make particular item "selected"? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the item is what you want to select like this:

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3];
const selected = 2;

for(var i in items) {
  let item = items[i];
  let option = $("<option></option>");

  if(item == selected) {
    option.attr('selected', true);
  }
  
  $("#Selectbox").append(option.attr("value", item).text(item));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Selectbox">
  <option>Select an item</option>
</select>
```